# Stripe implementation - error TS2339: Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'Stripe'

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe in Angular 7 project and i am running to some issues.

I am following this documentation on the Stripe official site : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder

After i instal npm install --save stripe and npm install --save @types/stripe-v3 and copy pasting all the code i get error.

```
document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
method: "POST",
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
},
body: JSON.stringify(purchase)
})
.then(function (result) {
return result.json();
})
.then(function (data) {
var elements = stripe.elements();

var style = {
  base: {
    color: "#32325d",
    fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
    fontSize: "16px",
    "::placeholder": {
      color: "#32325d"
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
    color: "#fa755a",
    iconColor: "#fa755a"
  }
};
```

The error happens in initializing the var elements to stripe.element() and it says
**Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'Stripe'.**

Anyone can help me out here?

Comment: "@types/stripe-v3" is an unofficial third party definition. Stripe has an official Typescript package for the stripe.js library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/stripe-js#typescript-support maybe using that would help?

Comment: @karllekko When i try to use the same example i get this error Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'esnext' or 'system', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher. and even if i edit them i am still get error

Comment: Did you manage to solve it finally? I have the same issue...

Answer (score 2):

`Stripe.js` uses `iframe` to load and show `elements` from [stripe.com](https://stripe.com), but because of cross-origin *security* reasons, browsers only allow this if the `.js` file was loaded from the same "origin" that the `iframe` is refering to.

Now, because of said limitations, `elements` is removed from `npm` package.

I mean, there are 2 variants of code for Stripe, and you seem to need the `window.Stripe` variant:

```html
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```